# Azure virtual machine image disables AutoLogin when deployed

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, windows-server

I have created an image from a virtual machine with AutoLogin enabled and programs set to run on startup, when I deploy virtual machines from the image it will only sign in when using RDP. I had the same thing setup with Amazon Web Services using an AMI.

How would I create a disk image on Azure preconfigured to sign in and run a program when I deploy it automatically?

Comment: Do you want to autoLogin when your VM start?  Does your program need user login to startup?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Yeah I'd like an account to automatically login when the VM starts after being deployed via a pre prepaired image, the program requires a user to be logged in before it will run. I'm using windows server 2016 with a full desktop environment as a base.